# How do I stop Google Chrome from translating English to English in Outlook.com

Tags: google-chrome, outlook.com

Google Chrome is translating English to English in Outlook.com. I am in the Czech Republic. Unfortunately the translation of my English to English is making my emails not make sense.

Google had a pop up that asked if I would like to translate the English in my Emails to English, but I did not click yes. I just closed the pop up.

Comment: Are you sure this is Google Chrome asking, not outlook.com? Could you attach a screenshot?

Comment: If it is Google Chrome asking, then this question is off topic here as it's about the browser and not the web application.

Answer (score 1):

Go to google chrome settings page. Click "Show advanced settings" and untick "Offer to translate pages that aren't in a language that I read" box near the bottom.

This will turn of translation everywhere so if you use it elsewhere don't do this.

Comment: I have this issue, and this didn't solve it: Chrome continued to translate - not just offer, but actually translate - English to English on the page.

Comment: this is crazy annoying - earlier today I needed an email translated (from swiss) and now all day google offers to translate my english emails to english, even as I am typing them... further, I turned off google translate like this suggested and it did not stop google translate